# How to format the row based on condition in kendo ui mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to display list of messages in a Kendo mvc ui grid. 
I have written the code like,

```
Html.Kendo().Grid((List<messages>)ViewBag.Messages))
                .Name("grdIndox")
                .Sortable(m => m.Enabled(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "" })
                .Columns(
                col =>
                {
                    col.Bound(o => o.RecNo).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none" }).Title("").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none" });
                    col.Bound(o => o.NoteDate).Title("Date").Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}");
                    col.Bound(o => o.PatName).Title("Patient");
                    col.Bound(o => o.NoteType).Title("Type");
                    col.Bound(o => o.Subject);

                }

                )
                .Pageable()
                .Selectable(sel => sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
                .DataSource(

                           ds => ds.Ajax().ServerOperation(false).Model(m => m.Id(modelid => modelid.RecNo))
                         .PageSize(10)
                            //.Read(read => read.Action("Messages_Read", "Msg"))
                )

                .Events(ev => ev.Change("onSelectingGirdRow"))
                )
```

and i have the field in the table like IsRead-boolean type. so if the message is unread message then i need to format that record with bold font. I have used clientTemplates but with that i am able to format only particular cells i want format entire row. Please guide me.

Answer (score 18):

as Sanja suggested you can use the dataBound event but it will be better to cycle through the **tr** elements (the rows). Also I assume that you will need the related [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem) to check if the property that indicates if the message is read.

e.g.

```
dataBound: function ()
{
   var grid = this;
   grid.tbody.find('>tr').each(function(){
     var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
     if(!dataItem.IsMessageRead)
      {
         $(this).addClass('someBoldClass');
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like $(this).find("tr").each(function()...?
The way you wrote it, it will cycle through all of TRs on the page.

Comment: That's right, I updated my post and now it cycles only through the direct children rows of the Grid table element.

Comment: is it true that if you user server data binding, ala DataSource(                   ds => ds.Server(), you cannot access the underlying data item in the javascript using grid.dataItem(this) ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use dataBound event to change your rows.

```
dataBound: function ()
{
   $('td').each(function(){
     if(some condition...)
      {
         $(this).addClass('someBoldClass')}
      }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do that.It's called [RowAction](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#methods-RowAction(System.Action%3CKendo.Mvc.UI.GridRow%3CT%3E%3E)).

```
.RowAction(row => 
{
   if (condition)
   {
      row.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "someBoldClass";
   }
})
```

Please note that  the **RowAction** is available only for rows that are rendered on **server side**. So in your case, you can use **RowAction** as an alternative to **DataBound**.